# Difference between PWM1H and PWM1L?

Tags: microcontroller

I'm new to microcontroller. In the PWM function, I do not understand what is difference between PWM waveform output high (PWMH) and PWM wave form output low (PWML). Can you explain this for me?

Comment: This is a better fit for electronics.stackexchange.com... Also: Which uC? Are these pin names, or settings names?

Answer (score 0):

PWML is inverted version of PWMH. 1 stands for 1st channel . This probably needs to provide driving pulses for inverter circuit.

Better option would be look into datasheet of controller you are using.